# Laravel PHP 8 blade -> getting a list of all parent table records, list them in a select element and selecting the record->name based on the foreignID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

So to break that title down...
I have 2 tables -> bosses (parent table) & employees (child)
bosses hasMany employees and employees hasOne boss

What I need to accomplish is to list all the bosses in an  element and "select" the current boss. And if I change the boss from the list, it should change the id of the element to the new selection.

```
@foreach ($bosses as $boss) 
  <option value="{{ $boss->id }}" {{ $boss->id == ($employee->boss_id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
    {{ $boss->full_name }}
  </option>
@endforeach
```

Controller

```
public function details($id){
    $employee = Employee::find($id);
    $bosses = Boss::get();
    return view('employees.details',[
        'employee' => $employee,
        'bosses' => $bosses,
    ] );
}
```

Right now I'm still setting everything up so the search isn't working.

With the above code I'm getting all of the $publishers listed by name but it is not selecting the the boss associated the the boss_id foreign key.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Where is the $employee coming from? Is it a single employee? Can I see the $employee and $bosses query from your controller?

Comment: I added the controller code

Comment: Where does `$publishers` come into it?

Comment: You don't have `$employee` set in any of the code above.

Comment: sorry copied wrong controller code.

Comment: I'd dump the `$employee` and `$boss->id` values and see if they are actually equal. Also try removing the parentheses around `($employee->boss_id)`. I don't think they'd affect anything but they're not needed either.

Comment: Try: `{{ ($boss->id == $employee->boss_id) ? 'selected' : false }}`. Adding the condition in one paranthesis. The rest of your code seems fine to me.

Comment: NIce! This worked! The code worked but was behind the actual value by 1. I didn't realize that due to my table setup I needed to +1 the employee->boss_id. But your solution worked!!!!!! Thank you immensely!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the helper method [old()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-old) for this.

For example:

```php
<select name="boss_id>
@foreach ($bosses as $boss) 
<option value="{{ $boss->id }}" {{ (old('boss_id', $boss->id) == $employee->boss_id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
```

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#repopulating-forms

Comment: This almost works! it loads the publisher that is the id-1 ?